# How to create Public URL for Django Localhost to access in Other Machines

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, django-rest-framework

I'm working Django Project.

1. How to create a Public IP permanently for Localhost(127.0.0.1:8000) IP in Django Project.
2. After Creating Public URL, how to allow access for Other users without Source Code

when I run **python manage.py runserver x.x.x.x:8088** in command prompt it is generating a URL with specified IP address. But when I share/open this URL with others it is not working

Can any one help me to configure this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to share your localhost with others you should use a programmable network edge like [https://ngrok.com/](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: @SaeedRamezani Yeah we can generate a Global URL using "ngrok" but it has Time Period of 2 hours. But I need to fix it as permanent  URL

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, you would either need to make use of a DDNS or buy a static IP. Why not just host it on a cloud instance?

Comment: yes, I think there is no any free way to use a permanent URL( if you find share me :) ). use cloud hosting or buy an enterprise edition of ngrok

Comment: Thanks @SaeedRamezani Yeah Sure if i found any i will share

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for this purpose

After running the server, you can open the HTTP(s) tunnel with `ngrok`

```bash
./ngrok 8000
```

and you will get the public URL of your service.

On free version the URL will be vary each time you run `ngrok`